# Spring Mvc and MediaType for consumes in @RequestMapping for a get rest request

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm implementing a REST application using Spring Boot. 
I want to specify the `consumes` parameter for the `@RequestMapping` annotation.
The rest call should be something like:

```
http: // mysite.com/resource/123
```

In the controller I handle this as follows:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/resource/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
consumes = XXX, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public Scenario getResource(@PathVariable("id") final long id) {
        //...
    }
```

The default value, i.e. all, is obvious and not specific. So, which should be the correct `MediaType` for `consumes`?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), `consumes` has to match the value of `Content-Type` header so the value you need to send for the mapping depends on what the client sets in the header.

Comment: What about the example with the id? Which would be the correct MediaType?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you askig what is the right way from the REST point of view?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With just a path variable, you do not need any content type. If you leave it blank, Spring will map all `/resource/{id}` requests to this handler regardless of the content type header. If you want to specify a content type, choose a default one like `text/plain`. But be aware that you have to change the request to have the same content-type header.

Answer (score 0):

To consume data from url path or url query param, you don't need to explicitly specify any media format. It works with the default format.

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/resource/{id}"}, method={RequestMethod.GET})
public String getResource1(@PathVariable("id") Long id){
    // other code here
    return "";
}

@RequestMapping(value={"/resource/{id}"}, method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String getResource2(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @ModelAttribute Person person){
    // other code here
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirements. If you only want to allow consumption of `JSON`, for example, then:

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, ...)
```

If you want to consume multiple media types, then you can specify them in an array:

```
@RequestMapping(consumes = {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
}, ...)
```